# How can I scaffold with bootstrap different number of columns?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, scaffold

Is there a way to scaffold on a fluid layout two rows with the one having 3 the other 4 and have those centered on my page.

```
            _________________  __________________  ______________________ 
            ______________ _______________  ______________  _____________
```

The problem is that I use the first and the last grid column to center and then I have 10 columns and not been 
able to separate them properly.

Comment: Why do you use the first and last grid column to center? Wouldn't that mean you would use 12 "span1" classes, with the first and last empty? The row amounts don't matter, so long as they add up to 12. Use class "row-fluid".

Comment: Yes I use 12 span1, is there a better way to center ?

Comment: Post a http://jsfiddle.net/ of your html / css code. You can center by using `margin: 0 auto;` on the wrapper container div. Other than that, I'm not sure I understand what the problem is.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using the `offset*`classes?

http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/scaffolding.html

Comment: I can't do what I need with the offset classes because the 3 columns are not going to be centered.

Comment: Can you post a `jsfiddle` or similar?